# Emacs Slow and Lags Often - How to debug?

Tags: emacs

My Emacs lags a lot sometimes. It seems like its after I invoke certain plugins but I am not sure. I've optimised my startup time, such that it autoloads them.

Sometimes, it takes a few seconds for it do what I typed and in other instances, it just goes to the background and when I open it, it crashes and core dumps. The output of the dump is usually some C function that crashed.

How can I debug the performance during runtime, and pinpoint which libraries are the cause? It could be a memory leak, but again, I have no clue.

I suspect its either the `expand-region` plugin or the `grizzl` plugin.

I run Emacs 24 in terminal on OS X.

Any help would be much appreciated!

Answer (score 21):

I suggest you try `M-x profiler-start RET RET`, then reproduce the slow behavior (maybe even a few times, since this is a sampling-based profiler), then `M-x profiler-report RET`.  Then `C-u RET` on the first entry should hopefully show you where time is spent.

As for the crash: any crash is a very likely sign of a bug in Emacs, so `M-x report-emacs-bug`.

Comment: Awesome thanks! Seems like 26% was spent on `flycheck-handle-signal`. Is there any way to make flycheck more efficient or faster? Or is there another alternative? What do you use for syntax checking? The second thing that was using 22% is `file-truename` which seems to be the f.el package (that does not seem to be used by anything I have so I'm not sure why it's there).

Comment: I also seem to crash on the functions `Ffind_file_name_handler`, `fast_string_match` and `re_search`. I use `'isearch-forward-regexp` as my search. Is that known to be slow? Is there something faster?

Comment: Actually file-truename is not in f.el. It is also used for `file-symlink-p` which seems to take about 20% CPU. I tried looking for this function but can't find it anywhere. Any idea what this is?

Comment: `file-truename` taking 22% of the time probably doesn't mean that `file-truename` is unusually slow but rather that something is calling it too often, so you need to look at the functions up the tree to see what is calling `file-truename`.

Answer (score 8):

Do `M-x toggle-debug-on-quit`, and then hit `C-g` during the next lag.  You'll get a backtrace that includes the command/function being evaluated at this time, and typically there's some suspicious function whose name gives the plugin away, which causes the lags.